# Java: Adding included Jar files to a created Jar file in linux

Tags: java, classpath

I need help including imported jar files into my java program in Linux.  Here is the program:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class CreateCoffees
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
             Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"); 
        }
        catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
            System.exit(1);
         }
    }
}
```

In order to execute `Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");` I need two `.jar` files added into the classpath:

```
db2jcc_license_cu.jar
db2jcc4.jar
```

I put these jar files into the same directory as my CreateCoffees.java file, then compile and run it like this:

```
javac CreateCoffees.java 
java CreateCoffees
```

But I got this error

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Then I tried the "-classpath" option

```
javac -classpath ./db2jcc_license_cu.jar:./db2jcc4.jar CreateCoffees.java
java -classpath ./db2jcc_license_cu.jar:./db2jcc4.jar CreateCoffees
```

but got this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CreateCoffees
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CreateCoffees
```

How to I include those jar files into a my runnable jar so I can run it with `java -jar myjar.jar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
java -classpath ./db2jcc_license_cu.jar:./db2jcc4.jar:. CreateCoffees
```

when you use `-classpath` it looses current directory from classpath so it needs `.` in classpath as well explicitly

Answer (score 0):

**How to include the jars of your project into your runnable jar:**

I'll walk you through it step by step with Eclipse Version: 3.7.2 running on Ubuntu 12.10.  I'll also show you how to make the `build.xml` so you can do the `ant jar` from command line and create your jar with other imported jars extracted into it.

Basically you ask Eclipse to construct the build.xml that imports your libraries into your jar for you.

1. Fire up Eclipse and make a new Java project, make a new package 'mypackage', add your main class: `Runner`  Put this code in there.

   [image]
2. Now include the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar` [from Oracle](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) which enables us to write Java to connect to the MySQL database.  Do this by right clicking the project -> properties -> java build path -> Add External Jar -> pick mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar.
3. Run the program within eclipse, it should run, and tell you that the username/password is invalid which means Eclipse is properly configured with the jar.
4. In Eclipse go to `File` -> `Export` -> `Java` -> `Runnable Jar File`.  You will see this dialog:

   [image]

   Make sure to set up the 'save as ant script' checkbox.  That is what makes it so you can use the commandline to do an `ant jar` later.
5. Then go to the terminal and look at the ant script:

   [image]

So you see, I ran the jar and it didn't error out because it found the included `mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar` embedded inside `Hello.jar`.

Look inside Hello.jar:  `vi Hello.jar` and you will see many references to `com/mysql/jdbc/stuff.class`

To do `ant jar` on the commandline to do all this automatically: Rename `buildant.xml` to `build.xml`, and change the target name from `create_run_jar` to `jar`.

Then, from within `MyProject` you type `ant jar` and boom.  You've got your jar inside MyProject.  And you can invoke it using `java -jar Hello.jar` and it all works.